# Script to listen to multiple multicasting ports in Python

Tags: python, twisted, multicast

I'm writing a script that needs to listen to a number of different ports for multicasts. Whenever a message comes in, I want to do different actions depending on which port it came in to. (Eg, log to different files)

My first thought was to use Twisted (or similar), for example by expaning the multicast example in their doco (https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/udp.html), but call the one protocol class multiple times, eg:

```
reactor.listenMulticast(8005, MulticastPingClient(), listenMultiple=True)
reactor.listenMulticast(8006, MulticastPingClient(), listenMultiple=True)
reactor.run()
```

And then use datagramReceieved to do different actions based on the port. This doesn't work, and I strongly suspect it's not the best approach.

I know this is a broad question, but hopefully what I aim to achieve is clear. I'm not tied to any framework (just Python). Any pointers for an elegant solution would be greatly appreciated. Factories seemed like they would be a reasonable approach, but they (logically) aren't supported for stateless protocols.

Comment: "This doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm very curious what goes wrong.  With Multicast, "it's a problem with your local network configuration" is always a good guess, but if one port works with Twisted, so should multiple...

Comment: It does indeed work - my bad. The serial device server on the other end was configured incorrectly, so it was providing some incorrect port information.